# Destroy an object and replace with a prefab at original objects location?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

The green balls search out for white ones and "infect" them. The white balls are destroyed but they come back at the point of origin. I've tried to make a variable of the position of the white balls but I keep running into "Can't convert Transform to Vector3" errors.

```
public Rigidbody prefabInfection;
public Transform infectLocation;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision colInfo)
{
    if (colInfo.collider.tag == "Infection")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Instantiate(prefabInfection);
    }
}
```

That's the code that's currently being used on collision.

I'm new to Unity also. Should I not destroy the white balls and instead somehow turn them into green balls? Is that possible?

Instantiation seemed like the only way. All I want to do is replace the white "human" balls to green "infection" ones.

Comment: "Should I not destroy the white balls and instead somehow turn them into green balls? Is that possible?" yes you should do that.  either go the enable/disable approach of object pooling (youll need that if you plan replace the balls with actual models in the future) https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling or switch out their shared material https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterials.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're seeing is probably because you're using the `Transform` object instead of its `.position`. Assuming your code is a component on the white ball gameObject, try this:

```
public Rigidbody prefabInfection;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision colInfo)
{
    if (colInfo.collider.tag == "Infection")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Instantiate(prefabInfection, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

By passing your `transform.position` to the Instantiate function, the new object will be created in the same position as the one you're destroying. Hopefully this is the behaviour you intended!

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

<del>Because you're destroying the current object, your script will never instantiate the new object because it's been destroyed before it got the chance to.</del>

```
Instantiate(prefabInfection, gameObject.transform.position);
Destroy(gameObject);
```

If you do it in this order, and pass in the position of the object, it should work how you intend it to.

EDIT: I've just learned that Destroy will actually wait until the current `Update()` frame has finished to destroy objects. I'm going to leave my answer up because I still think that's it is a better practice to call `Destroy()` last.

Comment: That's not true; the `Destroy` won't actually happen until end of frame (use `DestroyImmediate` if you require otherwise) - but there's nowhere the position is passed. Also, instantiating a `RigidBody` field doesn't just instantiate the `RigidBody` - it simply means that the instantiated object must _include_ a `RigidBody` component.

Comment: @DanPuzey I learn new things every day! I've had problems doing exactly what the OP has done in the past, so I figured that my fix would work for them.